# How to implement grouped tabled view sign in page

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I implement the login screen in the setting like the image below? 
I can't find the tutorial..
What I know is grouped table view only, I want to know how to do the username and password text input like that

[image]

Comment: you can create a custom view with two text field and image view, than apply a separator and placeholders, it is not strictly needed a grouped table view.

Comment: see this link bro , it is easy to optomize your work http://ranga-iphone-developer.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-create-login-section-using-table.html

Comment: see this also http://blog.encomiabile.it/2013/02/08/how-to-activate-next-uitextfield-in-uitableview-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple first TableView Cell have

- UIImageView
- UITextField
- UITextField

The others are more simple just need to manage the click event to provide appropriate implementation.
If you want a tutorial about handling UITextFields in tableview [here](http://blog.encomiabile.it/2013/02/08/how-to-activate-next-uitextfield-in-uitableview-ios/) it is.